# Request for guidance on integrating IBM RXN services using the Python wrapper

Tags: python, flutter

I am a beginner developer who is currently exploring the use of the IBM RXN services. I came across your Python wrapper on GitHub and I am interested in using it to integrate the IBM RXN services into my flutter application, but I am not sure how to proceed.

As a beginner, I was wondering if you could provide some guidance on how to use the wrapper to integrate the IBM RXN services, or if there are any examples or tutorials available that I could refer to. I would appreciate any help or advice that you could provide.

I have been trying to integrate the IBM RXN services using the Python wrapper available on GitHub. I have looked through the documentation and tried running the example code provided, but I am still having trouble getting it to work. My expectation is to be able to use the wrapper to make requests to the IBM RXN services and receive the appropriate responses from my flutter app.